# how to make custom modules accessibly globally

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have written several custom nodejs modules and I want to be able to access them anywhere I run my node apps. I have tried placing them in the same directory I installed nodejs in, but that doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how to do this?

Basically, this is what I want to be able to do:

```
`custom.js` 
exports.foo = function() {
     console.log("bar"); 
}

`app.js` 
var custom = require("custom"); 
custom.foo() //output: "bar"
```

Comment: The manual has the solution, duh. http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules

Comment: Using this approach I would still need to place my module inside my working directory. Instead what I want to achieve is having my custom module available globally, like the native nodejs modules. The `http` and `url` modules, for instance, don't need to be placed in the working directory in order to be imported with a `require()` statement.